# How to pass data in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with code in vuejs :

```
    data() {
     return {
        name:'',
        age: '',
     }
    }    
    created() {
      // Get name and age values ​​from methods
      console.log(this.name, this.age) //result null
    },
    methods: {
      changeValue:function (name, age) {
         this.name = name,
         this.age = age,
         console.log(name, age); // result : rooney, 20
     }
    }
```

I want to pass values ​​from `methods` to `created()`, how do I pass it? Give me ideas, thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do: the `created()` is a lifecycle hook that is invoked _once_ when the component is created. Therefore any changes to `this.name` and `this.age` will not be registered in there. Do you mean you want to **watch** changes to these values instead?

Comment: @Terry I use `localStorage.setItem('name', name);` to save the value for it.. and in create i want to pass that value up for me to process, i will be happy if you give me the code

Comment: @oikhanh please take a look at the [vue cookbook example to work with local storage](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html) and please be aware of the [vue lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In VueJs you cannot pass values between lifecycle hooks.**

However in the created hook, all reactive elements are already hooked up to your instance, so you can access your data objects as shown in the [official documentation example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

### what happens in your example

since created is called immediatly after your component is instantiated and reactivity has been set up (before it is attached to DOM elements), all your data will contain its default values. In this case for both elements that is `''`.

Any calls to the changeValue method from outside will happen after your component is mounted. For more information on this, please check the [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)

### A guess to what you tried to do

in the comments you mention that you set a name using `localStorage.setItem('name', name)`. Now, vue has no direct link to localstorage. All reactivity in vue happens through the data defined in the data block, which is accessible through `this` in most other places. If you want a parent component to pass this value to your component, you can do so with [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) (a.k.a properties/parameters). Or if you want to pass it from a child to a parent, you can do so using [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

reacting to those changes can then be done using [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on those data values or properties

### code example

```
props() {
    name:{type: String, default: ''},
    age: {type: Number, default: -1},
}    
watch:{
  name: function(oldName, newName){
     //this triggers when name is changed
     console.log(this.name, this.age)
     localStorage.setItem('name', newName)
  }
},
methods: {
  changeValue:function (name, age) {
     this.name = name,
     this.age = age,
     console.log(name, age); // result : rooney, 20
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank bro, I want when I call the api in `created()` to check if it has `name` or `age`.. if yes, get results by params, don't show all

Comment: this comment confuses me, i feel like you mean the vue api and not some web api. in the created() block, your name and age will always be on their default values as they are no props, props are variables you get as input from your parent component. In this case, checking the props would make sense, checking data in created will always be the same. For more info on props, check the link in the answer